# Converting a subList of an ArrayList to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

Im using an ArrayList and im trying to copy a part of it to another ArrayList therefore im using:

```
sibling.keys = (ArrayList<Integer>) keys.subList(mid, this.num);
```

Where "sibling.keys" is the new ArrayList and "keys or this.keys" is the older ArrayList.
I used the casting because eclipse told me to do that but then it throws a `ClassCastException`:

> java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Any advice?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`subList` returns a *view* on an existing list. It's not an `ArrayList`. You can create a *copy* of it:

```
sibling.keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(keys.subList(mid, this.num));
```

Or if you're happy with the view behaviour, try to change the type of `sibling.keys` to just be `List<Integer>` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>`, so that you don't need to make the copy:

```
sibling.keys = keys.subList(mid, this.num);
```

It's important that you understand the difference though - are you going to mutate `sibling.keys` (e.g. adding values to it or changing existing elements)? Are you going to mutate `keys`? Do you want mutation of one list to affect the other?

Comment: Another easy option that worked for me was sibling.keys.addAll(keys.subList(mid, this.num));

This is assuming that sibling.keys is already initialized. 

addAll() simply copies each item of the sublist.

Comment: Is this issue device specific? because same code is working for me on my Realme device but not on Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: @Lalchand: I suggest you ask a new question with a complete example and the very specific error you're getting. I would *expect* it to be the same across all Java implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You get the class cast exception because you are expecting an ArraList while the ArrayList.subList()does not return ArrayList.
**Change your sibling.keys from ArrayList to List**, and should work fine. This will avoid ClassCastException as well as you will not need to and any cast.