# when implementing a binary search in Java, is using ArrayList.sublist considered 'in place'?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search, sublist

The question is pretty much as stated in the title. I'm in an algorithms course and the professor and I disagree regarding whether or not operations performed on an ArrayList sublist (a sublist generated by ArrayList.sublist) can be considered 'in place'. To my read of the Java API:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations.

you are still manipulating the 'master' ArrayList directly. To his view, you are copying references from the 'master' array into a new sub-array which means employing ArrayList.subList is not considered 'in place'. Obviously, for the purposes of the course what he says goes (that is, if I want to pass :-/) but I would like to know either way for my own growth as a programmer. Code is below - and thank you!

```
public static int findK (int findME, int mVal, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {

    // pre stage return variable
    int returnVal = -1;

    // make a subarray consisting of indexes 0 - ((m-2)+(m-1)).
    // this because the relationship between the m, p, and q
    // is p>q>m - therfore the max value of q is m-1 and the
    // max value of p is m-2.
    int newArrSize = (mVal-2) + (mVal-1);
    ArrayList<Integer> subArr = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.subList(0, newArrSize));

    // make the list smaller by looking at only the last [mVal]
    // elements. this because we know what we're looking for
    // has to be in the second section of the array, and that
    // section can't possibly be larger than mVal
    int fromIndex = subArr.size() - mVal;
    subArr = new ArrayList<Integer> (subArr.subList(fromIndex, subArr.size()));

    // at this point we can do a simple binary search, which on an
    // a sorted array of size mVal is lg(m)
    while (subArr.size() > 1) {

        // get midpoint value
        int midPointIndex = subArr.size() / 2;
        int midPointValue = subArr.get(midPointIndex);

        // check for case where midpoint value is in the first
        // region of the array
        // check for case where the midpoint is less than the
        // findME value
        //
        // if true, discard first half of the array
        if ((midPointValue == 9000) || (midPointValue < findME)) {
            subArr = new ArrayList<Integer> (subArr.subList(midPointIndex, subArr.size()));
            continue;
        }
        // else if midpoint is less than findMe, discard the second
        // half of the array
        else if (midPointValue > findME) {
            subArr = new ArrayList<Integer> (subArr.subList(0, midPointIndex));
            continue;
        }

        // if we're here, we've found our value!
        returnVal = midPointValue;
        break;


    }


    // check for match and return result to caller
    // only perform check if we haven't already found the value
    // we're looking for
    if (returnVal == -1) returnVal = (subArr.get(0) == findME) ? (subArr.get(0)) : (-1);
    return returnVal;

}
```

Comment: "In-place" usually refers to modifications, I believe. A search does not modify anything. This is more a question of semantics, anyway; it's more important to understand the underlying concepts that to have a perfectly precise definition of every term. So basically: I wouldn't worry about it. If there's a chance saying it's "in-place" might confuse someone, find a term that is less ambiguous.

Comment: I think he's thinking that ArrayList.sublist somehow creates a whole new list and that adds to the complexity of the algorithm. That's what I'm debating with him about.

Comment: subList does not copy data. It merely references a range within the first list. It adds to the complexity, but is constant-time, so it's trivial

Comment: Take into consideration that sublist returns a view on the existing list and does not create a new one, according to this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644811/converting-a-sublist-of-an-arraylist-to-an-arraylist

Comment: that's what I figured but both he and the TA are insistent that a new list is made, even if the objects in the master aren't copied into the sublist. The TA did a few runs with the code above and a modified version using a primitive array and pointed to the performance difference. My assumption was that using objects in Java is going to add overhead, but again, they were pretty adamant which made me think I was missing something.

Comment: Your TA is cheating. A primitive array is pretty much guaranteed to be faster than an `ArrayList<Integer>` no matter what you do with it, and that test doesn't even have much to do with the issue at hand anyways. I'd just direct them to the source code, as nowhere in there can they prove that a new list is made. All that's made is a new *view*. The abundance of `ArrayList.this.___` and `parent.___` only show that the sublist delegates all work to the containing class.

Comment: source code - capital idea!! just checked the openJDK implantation and indeed it is performing the operation against the master list.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html

Comment: Just for completeness, you can usually access Oracle's source through your IDE and/or a `.jar` file hidden somewhere in `JAVA_HOME`, in case OpenJDK isn't good enough for your prof/TA

Comment: I feel as though we've arrived at a satisfactory answer (thanks for the alacrity, btw!). If somebody answers the thread I'll accept it so the thread can be closed.

Comment: Just a note, Will Hartung made a good point about the code you demonstrated. While `subList()` itself doesn't make a new list, passing it to a constructor definitely does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I assume in this answer, that by "in place" actually "uses constant additional memory" is meant.*

The sublist function creates a view of the original list. This uses only `O(1)` memory.

However you allocate a new list (Indices were replaced with my own names here, for simplicity):

```
subArr = new ArrayList<Integer> (subArr.subList(index1, index2));
```

What you do with such a statement is:

1. create a subList view (uses `O(1)` memory)
2. copy the sublist (uses `O(sublist size) = O(index2 - index1)` memory).
3. delete reference to subList (and by that the reference to the old list too)

Note that the garbage collector can not claim the memory of the old list until all references to it are deleted. The sublist view contains a reference to the old list, so the old list cannot be claimed by the GC until all references to the sublist view are deleted. This means for a short while you use `O(index2 - index1)` more memory than in the list at the beginning. Since binary search makes the list half as large in every step, you use `O(subArr.size())` additional memory (not in `O(1)`).

Answer (score 2):

Lines like these:

```
subArr = new ArrayList<Integer> (subArr.subList(fromIndex, subArr.size()));
```

That's your "copy". The new ArrayList is indeed, a copy of the data from the subList.

If you were using the subList "raw", then it could be better argued that you are "in place", because then the subList is simply a set of offsets in to the original array.

But with the create of new ArrayLists, you are definitely copying.

Of course, the easiest way to check is that when you find your value, change the value in the list to some sentinel (9999 or whatever). Then dump your original list. If 9999 shows up, it's in place. If not, then, it's not.

Comment: can you better explain what you mean by 'sublist raw'? To my read, this is simply casting the returned view as an ArrayList.

Comment: @DavidDaedalus This means simply doing `List<something> subArr = arr.subList(begin, end);` instead of passing the result of `subList()` to a constructor.

Comment: @DavidDaedalus `new X` always creates a new object. A cast would look like this: `(ArrayList<Integer>)subArr.subList(fromIndex, subArr.size())`, which should fail since it's not an `ArrayList`. Start getting into the habit of declaring your variables to be `List<Integer>` (the interface) so that you code continues to work if you decide you need to change list implementations for performance or what have you.

Comment: derp! I totally should've seen that what I was doing wasn't a cast:-)

Answer (score 0):

"In-place" isn't a term that applies to binary-search, as it almost always refers to how modifications are made (e.g. for sorting, like quicksort (in-place) and mergesort (not in-place)). So it's not something you need to worry about for binary search, as searching makes no modifications.

---

As for whether `ArrayList#subList()` copies data, a look at the source code should prove that that is incorrect. Unfortunately, the source is a tad long for a SO answer, but I'll do my best to summarize.

The `subList()` method is this:

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    subListRangeCheck(fromIndex, toIndex, size);
    return new SubList(this, 0, fromIndex, toIndex);
}
```

Where `SubList` is defined as the inner class:

```
private class SubList extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess
```

with instance fields

```
private final AbstractList<E> parent;
private final int parentOffset;
private final int offset;
int size;
```

Note how none of those fields are a type of array or list.

Looking at the implementations of mutators shows that all work is delegated to the parent class. For example, here is `set()`:

```
public E set(int index, E e) {
    rangeCheck(index);
    checkForComodification();
    E oldValue = ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);
    ArrayList.this.elementData[offset + index] = e;
    return oldValue;
}
```

Notice how `ArrayList.this` is used to refer to the containing `ArrayList` instance, which means that the *source* `ArrayList` implementation is modified and not any (nonexistent) copy.

The `add()` method shows something similar:

```
public void add(int index, E e) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);
    checkForComodification();
    parent.add(parentOffset + index, e);
    this.modCount = parent.modCount;
    this.size++;
}
```

`parent.add()` is used here, where `parent` is also the containing instance. So again, it is the source list that is modified, and not any (nonexistent) copy.

And so on and so forth.

---

However, as pointed out by Will Hartung, all this is moot if you pass the resulting `SubList` into the constructor of a `new ArrayList<>()`, as the constructor:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray(); // <------------ This line
    size = elementData.length;
    // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}
```

makes a copy of the internal array (through `toArray()`), which is the copy your professor/TA were likely talking about.